# ABS and ViewPager

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, menuitem

Im getting the following error when trying to use Menu-Items with my ViewPager + Fragments + ActionBarSherlock. Im almost certain this is a simple error that i just cant seem to figure out how to fix.

LogCat:

```
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at org.greenbot.technologies.solarphase.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:74)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:118)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:93)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:205)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1033)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-30 17:11:28.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This happens when i click on of my Menu Items in the below code.

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater Inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
    final int current = ((ViewPager) mFragments).getCurrentItem();
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(current);
    switch (Item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_back:
         web.goBack();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_forward:
        web.goForward();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        web.reload();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(Item);
}
```

Comment: What is line 118 in Watson.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mFragments` is an `ArrayList`, apparently. You are trying to cast it to be a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah see what im trying to do is to have my menu items control whatever fragment is being viewed in my viewpager. I've posted a question earlyier related to the menu items and my viewpager and fragments. mind taking a look at the question, its got my main source and im sure you will see what im trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844288/how-to-use-actionbar-items-with-viewpager-fragments